# Googlebot asks for png and then my whole Heroku site crashes. What is going on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, googlebot

Two days in a row my site has gone down and started responding with Error 500 to every request. Both times, I found this in the logs.

```
Started GET "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"
Processing by ShopsController#index as PNG
Parameters: {"page"=>"apple-touch-icon-precomposed"}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 25ms
F, [2013-09-06T04:15:13.827363 #2] FATAL
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat)
```

Followed immediately by hours of

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError 

(could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds)
```

and responding with 500 errors until I restart the server. I have increased the pool size, but I still can't understand why Googlebot asking for a PNG makes the database freak out and the whole site go down.

Answer (score 0):

The image should be requested as `/assets/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`. Without the `/assets` part it is delegated by the router to `ShopsController#index`, something you don't want.

Comment: But I have no control over how it gets requested. Googlebot has just decided to request that. I don't have any apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png on my site.