# Googlebot causes an invalid Cross Origin Request (COR) on Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cors, csrf, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How do I prevent Google from causing  this error while crawling the site? I am not interested in turning off "protect_from_forgery" unless it is safe to do so.

```
[fyi] method=GET path=/users format=*/* controller=users action=show status=200 duration=690.32 view=428.25 db=253.06 time=  host= user= user_agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) session= params={""} ()
[hmm] Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding. (pid:)
[fyi] method=GET path=/users/123/flag format=*/* controller=users action=flag status=500 error='ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest:Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.' duration=26.50 time= host= user= user_agent= session= params= (pid)
[omg] ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.):
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:217:in `verify_same_origin_request'
```

The controller responds with this

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render template: 'users/flag', layout: "some_layout" }
end
```

I am unable to recreate the bug and it seems to work fine when I do it through my browser

So far I've looked at the following resources but most seem to suggest just blindly turning of CSRF or are unanswered.

- [Using layout specific javascript in comfy leads to InvalidCrossOriginRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604414/using-layout-specific-javascript-in-comfy-leads-to-invalidcrossoriginrequest)
- [Invalid Cross Origin Request After Upgrading to Rails 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901978/invalid-cross-origin-request-after-upgrading-to-rails-4-1)
- [How to avoid ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209902/how-to-avoid-actioncontrollerinvalidcrossoriginrequest-exception)
- [Googlebot asks for png and then my whole Heroku site crashes. What is going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655437/googlebot-asks-for-png-and-then-my-whole-heroku-site-crashes-what-is-going-on)
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13345
- http://myownpirateradio.com/tag/rails-authentication-token/
- https://gist.github.com/aishek/8535082
- [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)
- http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428
- http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

---

To clarify:
The action should be protected from CSRF, But I want to prevent Google from crawling it or generating an error from crawling the page. Ie.) I want the false positive Security Warnings to go away without actually compromising my security features.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Googlebot is using the format "*/*" (http://apidock.com/rails/Mime) and the application renders the js since it's the only thing available. Since it's remote, it correctly causes an Invalid COR.

This was reproducible using:

```
curl -H "Accept: */*" https://www.example.com/users/123/flag
```

The fix is to have an html fallback resource for the spider to crawl:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render template: 'users/flag' }
  format.js { render template: 'users/flag', layout: "some_layout" }
end
```

Comment: Ordering is important here. format.html should come before format.js in the respond_to block.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, and the steps to reproduce described in the solution didn't work for me until I changed the header to `-H "Accept: */*"`, at which point I can now reproduce the error.

Comment: This suggestion will also raise errors "Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.", see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f80871fe6057d82fa218500e615a899245371071/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L252-L286.

Answer (score 1):

As per "CSRF protection from remote  tags " from the rails guide:

In the case of tests, where you also doing the client, change from:

> get :index, format: :js

To:

> xhr :get, :index, format: :js

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#csrf-protection-from-remote-script-tags

In the case you want to make this route skip csrf check, white list the route using something like:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

Comment: Does this resolve the issue when you're not in control of calling the endpoint? I've updated the tests already to use this .

Comment: To manage that also for the caller (and not only for test where you control the client) the guide says : "If you really mean to load JavaScript from remote <script> tags, skip CSRF protection on that action." - that is, adding in the controller something like "protect_from_forgery :except => :create "

Comment: absolutely none of those answers listed in the question solve this ! in my case, application.js is called by bots. Should I turn off forgery protection just for this file ?!